# Content Search Web Part and Workflow Task List

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I have a particular requirement of showing a particular user their workflow tasks in a webpart. I want to make use of Content Search WebPart as it supports paging and I have used this Webpart across the current page. 
I know using CQWB will solve my issue but I will have to do come xsl customization to bring in paging.

The issue is when I try and use CSWB it somehow refuses to pick any items from the Workflow task list, It works fine on other lists but just does not pick up values from Workflow Task List, anyone with some insight?

Using SharePoint Online/Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Check your task list settings if "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results? " is set to "Yes".

(List Settings - Advanced Settings -Allow items from this document library to appear in search results)